# Какова основная идея опции LOGGING/NOLOGGING при создании объектов БД?

Tags: sql, oracle

Что произойдет, если не указать `LOGGING/NOLOGGING` при создании объектов БД?

Точнее, как будут вести себя объекты БД с опцией `LOGGING/NOLOGGING` и без этой опции?

```
create table tab1 (col1 int, col2 varchar2(32)) 
/
create table tab2 (col1 int, col2 varchar2(32)) nologging 
/
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [What is the purpose of logging/nologging option in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34073532) от участника [@Sohel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535774/sohel)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/34073532

Answer (score 4):

`LOGGING/NOLOGGING` помогает управлять опцией *Direct path writes* (прямой путь записи в файлы данных), чтобы уменьшить генерацию *REDO* и *UNDO*.  Это один из нескольких способов контролировать деликатный баланс между восстанавливаемостью данных и производительностью.

**Немного общей информации по архитектуре**

*REDO* это то, как Oracle обеспечивает прочность (*durability*), "D" в ACID.  Когда транзакция завершается, изменения не обязательно сразу же сохраняются в файлах данных. Это ускоряет процесс и позволяет фоновым процессам справляться с некоторыми задачами. *REDO* - это описание изменений. Оно сохраняется быстро, на нескольких дисках, как журнал изменений. Если сервер теряет питание через доли секунды после фиксирования изменений, БД может через записи *REDO* убедиться, что изменения не потеряны, и востановить изменения ещё не записанные в файлы данных.

*UNDO* помогает обеспечить согласованность (*consistency*), "C" в ACID. В нем хранится описание того, как отменить изменение. Эта информация используется для отката изменений и другими процессами, которые читают таблицу и должны знать, какое значение *соответствовало* более раннему периоду времени.

*Direct path writes* не использует *REDO*, *UNDO*, кэш и некоторые другие функции, идёт непосредственная запись в файлы данных. Это быстрая, но потенциально опасная опция во многих средах, вот почему существует так много запутанных опций для управления ею. *Direct path writes* применяется только к `INSERT`, и только в сценариях, описанных ниже.

Если ничего не указывать, опция по умолчанию *самая безопасная*, `LOGGING`.

**Множество способов управления Direct Path Writes**

`LOGGING/NOLOGGING` - один из нескольких вариантов управления *Direct path writes*.

Посмотрите на эту таблицу из [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869), чтобы понять, как различные опции работают вместе:

```
Table Mode    Insert Mode     ArchiveLog mode      result
-----------   -------------   -----------------    ----------
LOGGING       APPEND          ARCHIVE LOG          redo generated
NOLOGGING     APPEND          ARCHIVE LOG          no redo
LOGGING       no append       ARCHIVE LOG          redo generated
NOLOGGING     no append       ARCHIVE LOG          redo generated
LOGGING       APPEND          noarchive log mode   no redo
NOLOGGING     APPEND          noarchive log mode   no redo
LOGGING       no append       noarchive log mode   redo generated
NOLOGGING     no append       noarchive log mode   redo generated
```

`FORCE LOGING` может отменить все эти настройки. Наверняка, есть другие параметры, о которых мало кто знает. И, конечно же, есть много ограничений, которые препятствуют прямому пути - триггеры, внешние ключи, кластер, индекс-организованные таблицы и т.д.

Правила в большей степени ограничены для индексов. Индекс *всегда* будет генерировать REDO во время DML выражений. Только DDL операторы, такие как `CREATE INDEX ... NOLOGGING` или `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` по индексу `NOLOGGING` не будет генерировать *REDO*.

Почему так много возможностей? Потому что восстанавливаемость невероятно важна, и разные стороны могут иметь разные взгляды на этот вопрос. И иногда решения одних людей должны преобладать над решениями других.

*Разработчики* решают на уровне запроса - "Вид на вставку".  Много странных вещей может произойти с подсказкой `/*+ APPEND */`, и разработчики должны тщательно выбирать, когда его использовать.

*Архитекторы* принимают решение на уровне объекта - "Вид на таблицу". Некоторые таблицы, независимо от того, как разработчик решит их вставить, всегда должны быть восстановлены.

*Администраторы БД" выбирают с видом на БД или табличные пространства, `NOARCHIVELOG` и `FORCE LOGING`. Может быть, организация просто не заботится о восстановлении конкретной БД, поэтому установят БД в режим `NOARCHIVELOG`. А может у организации есть строгое правило, что все должно быть восстанавливаемо, поэтому установят табличное пространство в режим `FORCE LOGGING`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34081775) от участника [@Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller)</sub>

Comment: Большое спасибо! Шикарный ответ!